# Extending Grothendieck topology from analytic manifolds to spaces?

Tags: stacks, sites, complex-analytic-spaces

Let $k\text{-Man}$ denote the *Euclidean* site of $k$-analytic manifolds where $k=\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$.  In words, $k\text{-Man}$ is the usual category of real/complex analytic manifolds considered together with their analytic morphisms.  The covers in this category are the usual topological covers, i.e. given by disjoint unions of open embeddings $U\rightarrow X$ where $U\subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ is an open subset for some $n$.

Now, let $k\text{-Spa}$ denote the larger category of $k$-analytic spaces.  Then the inclusions
$k\text{-Man}\subset k\text{-Spa}$ gives us a full subcategory, and we can ask the question of extending the Euclidean topology on $k\text{-Man}$.

**Question:**  Is there a unique extension of the Euclidean topology on $k\text{-Man}$ to $k\text{-Spa}$?  Here, I'm interested in various kinds of unique.  Isomorphic as sites is already interesting, but (probably?) more interesting is asking if the resulting toposes are isomorphic.

I'm interested in this question primarily because I'm currently being forced by a project into learning about stacks over the category of $k$-analytic spaces.  The literature is pretty scant here compared to the algebraic setting, but if anyone has any suggestions in this direction, I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: Since analytic spaces are locally ringed spaces, we have a natural Grothendieck topology: the one defined by open coverings. This will not get an equivalence of topoi with the category of sheaves on analytic manifolds: otherwise, analytic spaces wouldn't have any singularities.

Comment: A modern account on stacks over (derived) analytic spaces is the work of Mauro Porta and Tony Yue Yu:https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5166